# Runtime warnings when using scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

When putting this

`from sklearn import svm`

I am getting the following Error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321:
>   RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary
>   incompatibility   return f(*args, **kwds)

Most of the answers, when searching for the error, state out that it occurs, due to a version missmatch between Numpy & Scipy.

However, I couldn't find a clear solution.

How can I fix these warnings?

Comment: Well, what are you versions of numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, and python?

Comment: I'm using: numpy 1.8.1, scipy 0.14.0, scikit-learn 0.15.1, and python 3.4.1.

Comment: Also, I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.4.  I get the same error in the terminal and in Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 with Pydev.

Comment: @Banana In _bootstrap.py line 321 is the return command for a function def _call_with_frames_removed(f,*args,**kwds).  I looked at _bootstrap.py, but I couldn't find the cause of the warning.

Comment: How did you install the packages?

Comment: I installed the packages using pip3.  e.g. `pip3 install scikit-learn`